# R: Find the values of a 2D function (given by a matrix) along an arbitrary line

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix describing a 2D surface and I need to be able to calculate values along the surface for an arbitrary line.

This is best explained by an example

```
#x and y axes
x=c(1:100)
y=c(1:100)
# 2D Matrix function defined as 0 except for a middle box filled with 1
M=matrix(0,nrow=100,ncol=100)
M[40:60,40:60]=1
# define two points
x1=50
y1=50
x2=23
y2=80
# plot contour graph of M, add points (x1,y1) and (x2,y2)
# and a line connecting the two
contour(x,y,M)
points(x1,y1,col=2)
points(x2,y2,col=3)
lines(c(x1,x2),c(y1,y2),lty=2)
```

What I want to do is to get values of M along the line from (x1,y1) to (x2,y2), for instance at the values (xvec,yvec) where xvec=seq(x1,x2,length.out=N) and likewise for yvec.

Is there a simple way to do this in R?

Sincerely

Comment: What methods did you try so far?

Comment: The long way of doing would be to create a raster, draw a line, convert everything to spatial context and extract values from cells intersected by the said line *gasps for air*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually pretty easy using the capacity of the "[" function to accept a two column matrix (and here assuming `N <- 20`):

```
 M[ cbind(xvec,yvec) ]
 [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Because indices are truncated, the values won't necessary be those of the nearest points when the arguments are not integers.